# Proper way to load owned nested-resources in Laravel API

Tags: php, api, laravel-5

Using Laravel models, I have built the following structure

```
user-1
   company-1
        store-1
        store-2
   company-...
        store-1
   company-N
        store-1
        store-2
        store-n

user-2
    company-5
        store-12
user-3
    company-8
         store-15
    company-9
          store-21
```

That reads: an user have N companies and each company have N stores.

I have the following routes for that

```
$api->resource('companies', 'App\Http\Controllers\v1\CompaniesController');
$api->resource('companies.stores', 'App\Http\Controllers\v1\StoresController');
```

Right now, my CompaniesController is listing the companies as follows:

```
public function index() {
    return $this->response->collection(
        JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()->companies, new CompanyTransformer
    );
}
```

Which I don't think it's appropriate, but it's a working code ([for that I have posted a Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135899/how-to-decouple-resource-that-only-lists-items-owned-by-logged-user)).

Now, going down the rabbit hole, we have the next controller: StoresController

```
public function index($company) {
    $company = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()->companies->find($company);

    if(empty($company))
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();

    return $this->response->collection(
        JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()->companies->find($company)->stores, new StoresTransformer
    );
}
```

Here is where I'd say it's no longer an acceptable *Working Code*. In order to find all Stores from a given company, I have to `find()` between the user companies a specific company and check if it's not null (it exists) so I can return the proper list of stores. Imagine when I have to list a child of Stores? And if I have child resource of that child? The more I go down, the more ifs I'll have to perform to make sure the user owns that resource.

Am I missing something here? How do people give a list of owned resource given an Authenticated user?

Comment: Wait, why do you have to search starting with your users? Couldn't you just go straight to the company you are interested in and pull it's stores? (eg. /companies/1).

Comment: @georaldc What if the user has no permission to do that (i.e. The user doesn't own the company)? How do I prevent sneak users from accessing what they don't own?

Comment: I'm actually in the process of creating a web api too for work so I'm still figuring things out too just like you. I would imagine handling that server side though. Your jwt token probably has the data you already need to enforce proper authorization (scopes for example) so you could use that to control controller action access. For more fine grained control, you might find something useful in the laravel docs under the auth topic (https://laravel.com/docs/authorization)

Comment: @georaldc the IMPORTANT thing here is the fact that ALL users will have access to these methods. The "permission" is restricted to the content that gets served. So all users can call `/companies` but the list will differ according to what user is calling. The `companies/{company}` is also allowed for everybody, but if you pass an ID that you don't own, the server can't provide you any data.